# Error occurs when load data from HDFS into Spark with Hive built-in

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hiveql

I have put a file called test.txt into HDFS like this:

```
zeta@zeta-Satellite-L510:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/projects

15/05/19 15:43:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1 zeta supergroup   6 2015-05-14 15:37 /tmp/projects/test.txt

drwx------   - root supergroup   0 2015-05-14 13:49 /tmp/projects/sqoop
```

The file test.txt contains only :

```
1,2,3
```

And then I want to load it into Spark with Hive built-in using " LOAD DATA " command :

```
create table if not exists z(f1 int, f2 int, f3 int) 
   row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
   stored as textfile
   LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/projects/test.txt' 
   OVERWRITE INTO TABLE z;
```

But I get this error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10028]: Line 1:17 Path is not legal 
''hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/projects/test.txt'': 
Move from: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/projects/test.txt to:   
file:/home/zeta/abivin/vCore/AbiServer/warehouse/z is not valid. 
Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and 
"hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.
```

Here is my core-site.xml : http://pastebin.com/KLd4hsYR

My yarn-site.xml : http://pastebin.com/Z1BGBgZU

Hadoop version 2.6.0

Spark version 1.3.1

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this query working in hive console ??